# URL Rewriting for profile view

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to implement URL rewriting in my PHP application. Can someone share a step by step procedure of implementing URL rewriting in PHP using htaccess

In my application I want to implement following URL rewriting, I want to redirect
www.abc.com/profile.php?user=jack to www.abc.com/profile/jack

Please tell me how to implement url rewriting .

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)

In the public folder create a .htaccess file with this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /yourFolder/ #Optional
 RewriteRule profile/(.+) profile.php?user=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, something like this in an `.htaccess` file in your document root should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+) profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I suggest you read the guide for more information - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/